# How does git deal with content change at merge time if the file structure changed on the meantime in a separate branch?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I will describe the situation with this example for simplicity.

I have created a git branch at (Day 1) for my project, and the structure was the following:

[image]

I immediatly (still in Day1) changed the structure to the following :

[image]

In the meantime ( Day 2 ), the files Class1.java and Class2.java have changed in master branch by other prople (merge from an other branch to master).

My question is, when I will merge back my branch into master (Day 3) ... Will git keep the changes that have been done to Class1.java and Class2.java by the other people on master or it will replace them with the ones I have in my branch ?

Answer (score 1):

When you run `git merge <thing>`, Git has to find *three* commits.

One of the three commits is your *current* commit.  (Your index and work-tree should match it, and the front end `git merge` command usually enforces this.  It's generally unwise to run `git merge` in a "dirty" situation, though `git stash apply` does this all the time.  I recommend avoiding `git stash`, in part because of this.)

One of the three commits is, of course, the commit you name with your `<thing>` argument:

```
git merge theirbranch
```

picks the commit at the tip of their branch as the second of the two commits to merge.

The *third* commit is where most of the magic happens.  Git finds this third commit automatically.  Git calls this the *merge base*, and it's derived from the commit graph.  In some cases, it's easy to see where this comes from.

Suppose your branch and their branch have a very simple divergent structure:

```
          o--...--o   <-- yourbranch (HEAD)
         /
...--o--*
         \
          o--...--o   <-- theirbranch
```

The merge base of this structure is simply commit `*`.

In complicated setups, Git still finds the merge base on its own: the merge base is the *best common ancestor* of the two branch-tip commits to be merged.  You can, however, investigate before merging:

```
git merge-base --all theirbranch
```

will tell you which commit(s) are the merge base(s).  Ideally there's just one; when there are two or more, Git has a problem—which Git will solve, but (a) it's pretty rare and (b) it messes a bit with the rest of this description, so let's just ignore the problem for the moment. :-)

Having found just one merge base, Git now does this:

- `git diff --find-renames base your-commit` to see what you changed;
- `git diff --find-renames base their-commit` to see what they changed.

That is, Git runs `git diff` *twice*, using the *same* (common, shared) base commit.

Given the situation you described above, either *you* renamed some files, or *they* renamed some files—or, just possibly, both of you renamed some files.  The `--find-renames` option directs `git diff` to discover these renames.  (In this case, it was you that renamed files.)

Rename finding is not perfect, but in most cases it does exactly what's needed.  Git discovers which of you renamed which files.  This allows Git to *identify* the merge base file—which should be `folder1/src/Class1.java`—with the renamed file `folder2/src/Class1.java`.  Git remembers that the rename occurred, too.

In the diff for *their* changes, Git identifies the original file `folder1/src/Class1.java` with the not-renamed `folder1/src/Class1.java` in their final commit.

Since these changes are from identical *source* files, Git now combines your changes with their changes.  It tries to apply the *same* changes—including the rename—to the base file.  So Git gets the base commit's version of `folder1/src/Class1.java`, combines your changes and their changes—which may or may not conflict—and places the result in your index and work-tree as `folder2/src/Class1.java`, taking the (single) rename.

All of this combining fails if Git fails to identify the original base-commit files with the renamed files.  So you can run the same `git diff --find-renames`, perhaps with `--name-status` to skip looking at the actual diffs and just see what gets matched up.  If the right things get matched up, `git merge` will do the right thing.

If the right things *don't* get matched up, you can try tweaking Git's "rename threshold", specified as a number as `--find-renames=num`.  The number is a limit for Git's *similarity index*.  When Git compares two commits, such as the merge base and your current commit, if the merge base has a file `d1/d2/file.ext` but your commit doesn't, and your commit has `d3/d4/other.ext` that the base doesn't, Git compares the contents of the two files.  It then computes the similarity index.  This is, roughly, the *amount of the file that was carried over unchanged;* it maxes out at 100% similar, and if no parts of the files match, goes as low as 0% similar.  The default is to pair up files that are at least 50% similar.  If one source matches five destinations, Git will take the pairing with the highest similarity index, as long as it meets the threshold.

The `git merge` command takes the same parameter, but spells it `-X find-renames=number`.

#### If there are multiple merge bases

If `git merge-base --all` gives you more than one merge base, here's how Git deals with the problem:

- `-s recursive` (the default): Git first merges the merge bases, by running `git merge`, more or less, on them.  The resulting commit becomes the merge base.
- `-s resolve`: Git picks one of the merge bases at (apparently) random, and uses that.

All of the rest is the same, but note that if a recursive merge encounters a merge conflict, Git simply commits the merge conflict itself.  This conflicted merge result then becomes the input base, which typically causes weird-looking conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Git does delta updates, only the lines you changed will be merged.  If two or more people modify the same lines, you'll encounter a merge conflict and be required to fix it before you merge your changes in.

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches/merge-conflicts

Answer (score 0):

> Will git keep the changes that have been done to Class1.java and Class2.java by the other people on master or it will replace them with the ones I have in my branch?

Yes, Git's merge operation typically notices that you have renamed some files (you moved them into a different directory---that's a rename operation). The changes introduced by others in the original location in the meantime are carried over.

However, this works only as long as you do not reuse paths `folder1/src/Class*.java` on your side and the other side does not also introduce `Folder2/src/Class*.java` before the merge happens, because that would defeat Git's rename detection.

Comment: For your last "However" ... otherwise there will be a conflict or git will be lost ?

Comment: @Mehdi If the file exists on both sides of the merge, it will just be a normal content merge, possibly with conflicts. It would be irrelevant that one side renamed the file and placed a new file at its original location.